# Polymer.Dart's floating label for PaperInput not visible

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, polymer-elements

I have the example code in my Angular.Dart component:

`<paper-input bind-value="value" label="MyLabel" floatingLabel></paper-input>`

The paper input shows the value that is in my Angular.Dart component, but the floatingLabel does not appear. However, upon clicking the input, the label appears with the standard animation as if it was hidden. It seems as though this is a bug with the "constructor" of the paper-input element. I expected the floating label to appear above the input field when text is in the input field regardless if it was newly created or not. Is there a way to fix this glitch?

---

Progress: ([github.com/Polymer/paper-input/issues/117](http://github.com/Polymer/paper-input/issues/117))

I am looking intensively at the issue listed above, however implementing the fix accordingly is not as easy. As suggested by @GünterZöchbauer, I can use the `dart:js` library. However it appears that the solution was designed specifically for PolymerJs and not particularly for PolymerDart. Maybe I am overthinking things, but I am unable to perform a simple port.

But the issue does bring up a good point. The element is unable to detect the change (for what ever reason). So something needs to poke it to trigger an update. I currently have the dart context to the Element, however the class (`paper-input` is the class) does not contain the method `inputAction` upon inspection with WebStorm. However assuming that the `inputAction` method was firing an event, I can simply use the `dispatchEvent` method. However which event will trigger the event without modifying the object itself? And not crashing the browser would be great (I have been crashing the webpage with Chrome's `Aw, snap!` blue screen of death with some event tests).

Comment: What version of Angular, Polymer, and Polymer elements are you using?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Angular is at `1.1.2+2`, polymer is at `0.16.3+3`, paper_elements is at `0.7.1+1`, core_elements `0.7.1+4`

Comment: Looks a bit like https://github.com/Polymer/paper-input/issues/117 but there it is mentioned that this only happens for `<paper-input-decorator>` but not for `<paper-input>`.

Comment: It appears that `<paper-input-decorator>` is used inside the shadow dom of `<paper-input>` upon inspection with Chrome. So the issue is linked. @GünterZöchbauer The liked issue you posted mentions a work around using JavaScript to trigger an event into the input field to "refresh" its state, however I am unable to find a suitable replacement in Dart as I can not find the `inputAction` in JavaScript to verify what the command does. Any insight? Thanks for your help.

Comment: `dart:js` should allow that. `new JsObject(xxx).callMethod('inputAction', [])` (or `new JsObject.fromBrowserObject()`) or similar.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Added an update to my progress. I might be able to use the `dart:js` library if I can figure out how to convert the `Element` dart object to a JsObject for the use of `callMethod`.